# How come lost updates happen with volatile on x86?

Tags: java, x86, volatile

I tried running the following code with 'count' as a volatile:

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    e.execute(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
            count++;
            }
        }
    );
}
e.shutdown();
e.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
System.out.println(count);
```

count usually ends up less than 1,000,000.

I'm running on an x86 processor - Intel core 2 duo E8400 with hotspot 1.6.24.
The usual lost update argument against the ++ operator used with a volatile variable, with the intention of achieving atomic update, goes like this: 
Both threads 1 & 2 read value 0 for v, both increment it by 1 and write the value 1.

This argument seems to fall apart when using a volatile on an x86 since:

1) Every access to a volatile variable goes through the CPU cache hierarchy. The JVM can generate assembly code to access a volatile multiple times with no intervening load/store from memory only if it can prove the volatile variable is accessed by a single thread, which is not the case here.

2) Only one CPU can have a specific cache line in the modified state, so if both CPUs try to increment v, only one will succeed in getting the cache line containing v into the modified state. The other will have its cache line invalidated and only later will enter the modified state with its cache containing the correct value of 1 and will update the variable to 2.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the fact that ++ isn't an atomic operation.

If you rewrite your code as:

```
for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
    int tmp = count;
    tmp = tmp + 1;
    count = tmp;
}
```

does that make it clearer? There's no need for memory model or cache line details here - all we need is two threads both reading the same value, both doing independent work, and then both storing their computed value back again.

Answer (score 3):

`count++;` is the problem on ANY modern processor this needs `count` to be loaded into a register where it can be incremented (as no processor can operate directly on RAM) and then it is save back to RAM

use [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and use incrementAndGet

or in general a atomic compareAndSwap loop (here using a [AtomicFieldUpdater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.html) which only works on instance fields) is the fastest way to ensure the update always happens (this is vulnerable to the [ABA problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) though)

```
do{
    int old=count.get(this);
    int newval=old+1;
}while(!count.compareAndSet(this,old,newval));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first reasoning is correct and does not fall apart, no other thread will get a stale value, but if you probably fall into the trap that since count++ is only one instruction (in java) that it maps to a single instruction on the CPU.

Try thinking about it this way instead.

```
 Value is loaded from memory into register.
 Register is incremented.
 Value is written back.
```

There will be some time period between these operations so it would actually be the same code as:

```
 Value is loaded from memory into register.
 Do a lot of time-consuming things
 Register is incremented.
 Do a lot of time-consuming things
 Value is written back.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing this possibility:

1) The variable is shared in both CPU's caches.

2) Both CPUs read the value.

3) Both CPUs add one to the value, getting the same result.

4) CPU0 gets the variable exclusive in its cache and writes the incremented value.

5) CPU1 gets the variable exclusive from CPU0 and writes the same incremented value the cache line already held.

While `volatile` does prevent you from reading stale values, it doesn't provide atomicity.

Comment: This explanation is what I was looking for. So there are no stale values in the cpu's caches, but once the values are in registers you don't have the non staleness guarantee. Thanks!

Comment: @user378060 This applies even if the values never go in registers. Even a read-modify-write operation direct to memory is three operations: read, modify, write. Without a lock prefix, it's not atomic and the CPU can lose ownership of the memory address while it's modifying. If you look at my example, no CPU ever reads a stale value. They just overwrite a newer value.